# Independent Variables in Multiple Regression found Significant, but Insignificant when ran Individually

Tags: regression, minitab

I've ran into (by accident) something that has stopped me in my tracks. When running this analysis:

---

[image]

I get that Use, FA, and Detections are significant predictors for fixation duration on map duration. However, if I run individual regressions with those components, for instance, just with Use:

[image]

I see that Use is not actually a significant predictor at all.
Can anybody give me an idea of the next steps that I have? I've looked into collinearity and have run some initial correlations but nothing I get is shouting out to me as problematic.

Thanks all
-Sam

Comment: Are those categorical variables?

Comment: Yes, Tim, all of them are categorical variables.

Answer (score 0):

It’s primarily because your error terms change. The ‘by the book’ answer is that you should model all variables you have access to because it provides a clearer picture (statistical or otherwise) of the phenomenon. When you include additional factors your error term is smaller making it easier to reject the null hypothesis.